# Create Module For Send Order Notification on WhatsApp in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: api, magento2.3.2, integration, notification

**I Want To Create Module For Sending Place Order Message On WhatsApp..**

> Or Also Any Free Extension Available For This I Tried [WhatsApp Order
>   Notification](https://magecomp.com/magento-2-whatsapp-order-notification.html) But Its Paid I Want To Free Extension Or Create a
>   Extension

Comment: do with customization - https://github.com/magecomp/magento-2-whatsapp-notification-with-api

Comment: this is simple module with only backend configration

Comment: check with helper  files.

Comment: yes let me check and thank q @anas Mansuri